# Изменение значения перемнной от Даты - PHP

Tags: php, дата

Здравствуйте, есть начальная дата 01.01.2018, есть переменная $i = 0, как сделать так чтоб $i +1 каждый следующий месяц который я могу задавать типа апрель $i = 2, май $i = 3, если прошел год то $i = 12; как можно это сделать!

Comment: Задайте по нормальному вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Если просто добавить месяц к дате:

```
function addMonths($date,$months) {
  $orig_day = $date->format("d");
  $date->modify("+".$months." months");
  while ($date->format("d")<$orig_day && $date->format("d")<5) {
    $date->modify("-1 day");
  }
}
$d = new DateTime("2018-01-01");
// $i - целое число, сколько прибавить месяцев
addmonths($d,$i);
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку Warning: DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (+ months) at position 0 (+): Unexpected character in
Notice: Undefined variable: i in

Answer (score 0):

```
    $d1 = new DateTime('01.01.2018');
    $d2 = new DateTime('01.02.2019');

    $interval = $d2->diff($d1);
    $months = $interval->format('%m');

    echo 'Прошло: ' . $months . ' месяцев.';
```